# is there any better way to check array is array not empty

Tags: javascript, arrays

well, I did some R&D about array checking but can't find a more elegant way to check array.
is there any better way to check the array and it's not empty in javascript?

```
if (Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length > 0) {
  console.log(true)
}
```

Comment: This way is fine.  If you wanted to be more "elegant," then I guess you could move this logic into its own function.

Comment: this is already the best. if you want can shorten arr.length > 0 to just arr.length .

Comment: `arr.length > 0` - in some archaic codebase, I've found developers use `!!arr.length`. Not my personal choice & wouldn't prefer double-negation.

Comment: I'd consider this a failing test in some (odd) circumstances though it depends on your definition of "empty": [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/am3qg4bf/), I'd test the `length` after filtering the Array: [`arr.filter(Boolean).length`](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/am3qg4bf/1/). But it depends on your use-case of course.